# Ошибка при сборке curl

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

```
Linking C shared library libcurl.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libssl.a(s3_clnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libssl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libcurl.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/libcurl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Собирается с OpenSSL. Что значит эта ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Есть готовое решение на [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/696721/compile-curl-with-openssl)

```
openssl:

./config -fPIC no-gost no-shared no-zlib
make depend
make
make install 

curl:

./configure  --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
make 
make install
```

Comment: gost нужен как раз

Comment: Значит без no-gost

Comment: а с cmake как это сделать?